# Pass a From phone number to Dialogflow via a Twilio Integration

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Dialogflow Bot that is integrated with a Twilio phone number. I am trying to get Twilio to pass the "from" number that initiates an interaction to Dialogflow, so I can later log it in a fulfillment.

I put this in Fulfillment:

```
function reschedule(agent) {
    const OriginalDetectIntentRequest = agent.parameters.OriginalDetectIntentRequest;

then: axios.post('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/q0te84lfo1aal?sheet=Appointments', {
            "data": {
              "student": student,
              "to_date": to_date,
              "from_date": from_date,
              "created": new Date(),
              "OriginalDetectIntentRequest" : OriginalDetectIntentRequest,
            }
          });
```

Everything posts except the `OriginalDetectIntentRequest`.

Here's the reference: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/OriginalDetectIntentRequest

Comment: hi! can you include some code or screenshot of what you have

Comment: Hey sorry, new to posting! I'll edit the above since I can't seem to post code here in a way that makes sense...

Comment: Check [the help centre page on formatting your posts using markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to add formatting to your posts. For code, use triple backticks for code blocks and single backticks for in-line formatting. You can also review the [edit] history of your post to see how I've added the formatting.